# errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"?

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to create a relationship table between tags and articles, but I have a problem.

migration code:

```
 Schema::create('article_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('article_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('tag_id');
        $table->timestamps();



        $table->foreign('article_id')->references('id')->on('articles')->onDelete('cascade'); 
        $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags')->onDelete('cascade');
      });
```

the error:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `hiro_blog`.`article_tag` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `article_tag` add constraint `article_tag_article_id_foreign` foreign key (`article_id`) references `articles` (`id`) on delete cascade)

Comment: Do you already have table 'articles' before you try to add foreign key constraint ?

Comment: yes everything was ok since an hour, but when I tried to run "PHP artisan migrate: fresh" This problem appeared

Comment: Is the type integer length of this field in this table correspond to the integer length  type of the foreign table id

Comment: Can you show us your 3 migration file name (from the migrations directory)? `articles`, `tags` and `article_tag`

Comment: @Alexandr Blyakher I tried to list all possibilities:
$ table-> increments ('id');
$ table-> unsignedBigInteger ('user_id');
$ table-> id ();

Comment: EsTeAa  2021_03_15_141406_create_articales_table          2021_03_17_075931_create_tags_table      2021_03_20_075931_create_article_tag

Comment: If you want to delete all and create new then try with `php artisan migrate:refresh`

Comment: I did that but the problem still appear